# Checking that Server object connected

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, smo

I am working with `Server` object from  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` namespace.
How i can check that it connected successfully to the server i couldnt see there any property related to it .

```
                ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(server);
                // Log in using SQL authentication instead of Windows authentication
                srvConn.LoginSecure = false;
                // Give the login username
                srvConn.Login = serverUserName;
                // Give the login password
                srvConn.Password = serverPassword;
                // Create a new SQL Server object using the connection we created
                SqlServer = new Server(srvConn);
```

I want to know if connection was good with my username and password.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Smo doesn't connect to the server until you actually use the connection for something. According to Books Online:

> SMO will automatically establish a
>   connection when required, and release
>   the connection to the connection pool
>   after it has finished performing
>   operations.

That means you have two basic strategies:

1. Retrieve Server.Information.Version or another attribute to test the connection
2. Just go ahead and do what you want to do, and catch any exception

I would say that 2 is the better option, because there is no guarantee that a connection that works now will work again in a few seconds: the server or network can go down or your login can be disabled by a DBA. Handling connection failures from the beginning would be a good way to make your application more robust.